# Issue with application crashing when selecting visual effects and attempting to switch from gallery to speaker view in Twilio

Tags: background, twilio, galleryview

I'm facing a peculiar issue in my Twilio implementation and I could really use some assistance. In my application, I've integrated Twilio for video conferencing. However, I've encountered a problem specifically related to visual effects.

Here's the scenario: When I enable visual effects and then attempt to switch from the gallery view to the speaker view during a video conference, the application crashes. Strangely, this issue only arises when visual effects are enabled.

I've tried to isolate the problem by debugging the code and examining the error logs, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause. It's puzzling to me why visual effects seem to be triggering this problem.

I sincerely appreciate your assistance in advance. If any additional details are needed to better understand the problem, please don't hesitate to ask.